# Binding not working properly with ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, listbox

I'm binding a List of a custom class (which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged) into a ListBox.

When I add any item to the List, the ListBox doesn't update, **but if I scroll**, the ListBox gets updated.

The class

```
class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name = string.Empty;
    public string Name { /* INotifyPropertyChanged */ }
}
```

The property

```
private List<MyClass> loaded;
public List<MyClass> Loaded { /* INorutyPropertyChanged */ }
```

The ListBox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Loaded} />
```

If I force override the List property, it works fine:

```
Loaded = new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass { Name = "test"; } }
```

Comment: I downvoted, as the question info is incomplete. In one of the answers below, asking user tells about sockets.

Answer (score 1):

Update to:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> Loaded { get; private set; }
```

and

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Loaded, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} />
```

Also, you do not need to use `INotiftyPropertyChanged` for your `Loaded` property. If the binding happens once, and the data-source does not change, there's no need.

**Edit:**

Here's a working example.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
        </ListBox>
        <Button Width="100" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddItem}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new DataContext();
    }
}
```

**DataContext.cs**

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public class DataContext
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; private set; }
        public ICommand AddItem { get; private set; }

        public DataContext()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>
            {
                new Item
                {
                    Value = "test"
                }
            };
            AddItem = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                Items.Add(new Item
                {
                    Value = "new item"
                });
            }, () => true);
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**RelayCommand.cs**

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    private Action methodToExecute;
    private Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator;
    public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute, Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator)
    {
        this.methodToExecute = methodToExecute;
        this.canExecuteEvaluator = canExecuteEvaluator;
    }
    public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute)
        : this(methodToExecute, null)
    {
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.canExecuteEvaluator == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            bool result = this.canExecuteEvaluator.Invoke();
            return result;
        }
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.methodToExecute.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I realized the problem is because I'm using an asynchronous Socket and I'm getting an error about thread safety. The List property is created on the main thread, then I call BeginAcceptSocket and when a Client connects, it can't add on the List

Comment: ahh dang! awesome, at least you found the issue.

Comment: @hendoe In your question you didnt mention that.